# If statement within Predicate not working

Tags: ios, if-statement, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My `IF` statement within my `nsfetchresultscontroller`  is not working and I cannot figure out why. It is a simple `IF` statement based on the static title of the viewcontroller using  `if ([self.title isEqual: @"Abdominals"])` My storyboard can be seen below:

[image]

**ViewController**

```
  - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"ExcerciseInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"details.muscle" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Sort Results    
  if ([self.title isEqual: @"Abdominals"]) {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"details.muscle == %@", @"Biceps"];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    }

    else if ([self.title isEqual: @"Arms"]) {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"details.muscle == %@", @"Biceps"];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate ];

    }

    else {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"details.muscle == %@", @"Chest"];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate ];

 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do a `NSLog(@"%@",self.title)` and check the value, maybe your title is nil or have some other characters.

Comment: Thanks Danypata. It came up as Master. And when I changed one of my if statements to this it worked. I have fixed this now. Very silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `isEqualToString:`

`isEqual:` compares objects, where it appears you are wanting to compare values.

Comment: have you put a breakpoint or debug log to check what `self.title` is?

Comment: I did but to no avail. I presumed self.title was the title of the view contoller? Is it possible to target the seague instead?

Comment: All fixed with a debug. Thanks